# Using GitHub with WampServer? Or, only including certain directories?

Tags: git, github, wampserver

Forgive me if this has been asked before, but I've been doing a lot of searching and haven't been able to determine the best solution to my problem.

I've been the sole developer on a project that now will likely involve another person. Up until now, I have never used a version control system before, other than simply backing up my files every day (cave man's version control :-) ), but now I need a way for more than one person to update files.

After doing some research it seemed that GitHub would be a good choice, so I signed up for their cheapest plan and have been learning how to use it. I'm able to create repositories, update files, etc, but I have a problem which I'll detail below.

I'm using WampServer on my development computer so that I can test changes before uploading the modified files to my live server. I have the root directory of the site located here:

```
C:\wamp\www\[project]\www\
```

My website uses a CMS, which I have installed on my local computer, so there are thousands and thousands of CMS files located in subdirectories and I only want to have my "custom" files (i.e. non-CMS files) uploaded to GitHub.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

I read about the .gitignore file to exclude directories and after a quick test it seems to work, so what I'm wondering is: should I make a new Git repository based at `C:\wamp\www\[project]\www\` and then exclude all of the CMS's directories by putting them in the .gitignore file? It seems like this should work, but I want to make sure it's the right way to go about this.

Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove directories that you don't want to use from git control, add them to .gitignore, copy this directories back.

Comment: I understand the "add them to .gitignore" part, but what do you mean by "Remove directories that you don't want to use from git control" and "copy this directories back"?

Comment: copy them to another folder, apply git rm at your local copy for that folders, commit, add .gitignore, copy folders back, commit. something like this.